# ubuntu 14.04 boot from san

Tags: boot, grub2, iscsi

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on iscsi target and after reboot i get grub rescue prombt after error

**Boot sector id not valid**

**error: no such device : c098787-4839-34bh-3d4f-b3eef9i3j9f**

any advice ?